# Vue moment remove space

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I use moment like this

**pages/index.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="box">
        {{ item.updateDate | moment("from", "now") }}
    </div>
</template>
```

An example value of `item.updateDate` is **1580564625000**.

I use my vue-moment in zh-cn locale. It almost works fine as the moment filtered above is converted to **17 小时前**. Take note that it has a **SPACE** between 17 and the chinese words. I would like to remove the space like **17小时前** but how?

I am using the package

- "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
- "moment": "^2.24.0",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own filter in the component (or globally if you want to use it multiple times) for removing space, and chain it with moment filter.

```
filters: {
  removeSpace: function (value) {
    return value.replace(/\s/g, '')
  }
}
```

And

```
{{ item.updateDate | moment("from", "now") | removeSpace }}
```